# App crashes on startup after adding ImageView

Tags: java, android, crash, imageview

I am running a basic app with one ImageView. It runs until I add the following

```
ImageView gohan = findViewById(R.id.gohanView);
```

These are the only things that I've done:

- Created project
- Created empty activity
- Added ImageView to activity
- Imported image to drawable folder
- Attached image to src of ImageView
- RUN (Everything works at this point)
- I then add the code above to my MainActivity class and the app will not run anymore.

**Java**

```
package com.example.david.dragonballz;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView gohan = findViewById(R.id.gohanView);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gohanView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="69dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="114dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="114dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="114dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:src="@drawable/gohan"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
04-18 13:02:51.416 15392-15392/com.example.david.dragonballz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.david.dragonballz, PID: 15392
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.david.dragonballz/com.example.david.dragonballz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2839)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:117)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:56)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:198)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:183)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:519)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:190)
        at com.example.david.dragonballz.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:9)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

**Here is example of WORKING code from the Android classes I'm taking. Why does this work for him and used to work for me?**
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xToDV.png)

Comment: put  ImageView gohan = findViewById(R.id.gohanView); inside oncreate method after.setContentView.

Comment: You an get reference to any view in onCreate()

Answer (score 1):

Never find id of any views before `onCreate()` method because the xml layout is loaded on `onCreate()`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

find id in `onCreate()`

```
gohan = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.gohanView);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Declare this**

```
public ImageView gohan;
```

Add this line in oncreate()

```
gohan = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gohanView);
```

after this line

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Finally your onCreate()

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gohan = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gohanView);

 gohan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something 
           gohan.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
            }
        });
    }
```

**ALSO NOW ACCESS THIS IMAGEVIEW ANYWHERE**

Comment: Thanks! That allowed it to run but now I can't access "gohan" from another class.

I'm not sure what changed but I used to be able to have the ImageView in the MainActivity class and then access it when creating classes within the MainActivity. Does that make sense?

Comment: @INKALAXY, You can just declare the object as `ImageView gohan` in your activity and assign it in `onCreate` method. What do you mean by accessing it with classes within your activity? Why you wanted to do that?

Comment: Ok. So you're saying this should work:

`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    ImageView gohan;

    public void gohanClick (View view) {

        gohan.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView gohan = findViewById(R.id.gohanView);
    }
}`

Comment: okay wait let me update again

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Thanks again! I'm starting to get the hang of it now. However, I am still confused why the way I did it before is now not working. I have added a screenshot (low quality, sorry) to my original question. 

The code that I screenshot was working for the instructor and for me up until yesterday. Any ideas?

Comment: you have not done correctly